# How to filter Nunit test using VStest console and Nunit 3 adapter for VS?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit-3.0, vstest

I develop the following unit test using Nunit 3.6:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTest.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test_MarkedAsTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        [Explicit]
        public void Test_MarkedAsTestExplicit()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("Manual")]
        public void Test_MarkedAsTestManual()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("ShortRunning")]
        public void Test_MarkedAsTestShortRunning()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to filter the test upon its category. I am using VSTest to execute the test and following the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx)

When the command is executed without exclusions, 3 test ran (Explicit does not ran):
[image]

If test filter parameter is introduced, then "Explicit" test are executed:

[image]

If I try to filter, in order to execute the test NOT in the Manual or Explicit category, VSTest runs all the test
[image]

How to filter a category and the Explicit tests?

Comment: Use Category instead of TestCategory. See the VSTS answer here [Specify NUnit categories with TFS vNext (2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249366/specify-nunit-categories-with-tfs-vnext-2015)

Comment: That answer does not apply for the Nunit3 adapter for VS: vstest.console.exe : Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://nunit3testexecutor/': No tests matched the filter because it 
contains one or more properties that are not valid (Category, Category, Category, Category). Specify filter expression containing valid properties 
(FullyQualifiedName, Name, Priority, TestCategory) and try again.

Comment: Your comment saved me @XtianGIS. Please consider putting your comment as an answer, and I'd glady upvote it. EDIT: now that I look into it, this wasn't really your question :P

Comment: @XtianGIS did you find a solution to run the nunit3 test on vstest.  I'm having same problem.  I want to run nunit test using on vstest console.  Please let me know if you have figured out.  Thnaks.

Comment: @user3174886 I was able to run the tests, but I was not able to filter them as i want.

Comment: @XtianGIS I figured out a way for my purpose and it worked.  The solution worked for me is C:\Project\ProjectTest\bin\Debug>vstest.console.exe ProjectTest.dll /Logger:trx /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory="Sanity" /TestAdapterPath:"." on console